# C# casting and inheritance

Tags: c#, inheritance, casting

I have an object that I pass around a lot.

I need to add a piece of data to it and cannot modify the base class

So I have

```
static OriginalThing GetNewThing()
{
  return new OriginalThing();
}
```

Now i want to add my piece of data

```
class EnhancedThing : OriginalThing
{
  string name;
  static EnhancedThing GetNewThing(string name)
  {
     EnhancedThing ething = new OriginalThing();   <---doesnt work even if i cast it
     ething.Name = name;
  }
}
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can't assign an `OriginalThing` to a `NewThing` because it simply is *not* a `NewThing`.  The other way around works fine because a `NewThing` is capable of everything an `OriginalThing` is, but the reverse is not true.

Just create an instance of `EnhancedThing`, assign the name, and return it.   You can treat the `EnhancedThing` as if it were an `OriginalThing` because it *is* an `OriginalThing`.

```
class EnhancedThing : OriginalThing
{
  public string Name { get; private set; }
  static EnhancedThing GetNewThing(string name)
  {
     EnhanedThing thing = new EnhancedThing();
     thing.Name = name;
     return thing;
  }
}

// ...

OriginalThing foo = EnhancedThing.GetNewThing( "someName" );
```

Also realize that doesn't buy you much as `name` is currently a private member variable (in your example), and you won't be able to access any additional functionality of `NewThing` objects unless you treat them as `NewThing`s (as opposed to `OriginalThings`, but you can pass them around as `OriginalThing`s if needed)

Comment: Great explanation Ed.  I would just add that you may hear this discussed as Covariance vs. Contravariance (especially in an interview ;-)  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx

Comment: EnhancedThing ething = new OriginalThing();
when i do this it states that you cannot implicitly convert the type

Comment: @Jeff: That was a typo left over from copying your original code, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this:

```
EnhancedThing ething = new EnhancedThing();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because an OriginalThing is not an EnhancedThing, but an EnhancedThing is an OriginalThing.

One thing you could do is have a constructor for EnhancedThing that takes an OriginalThing and copies over the members that apply.

```
class EnhancedThing : OriginalThing
{
    public EnhancedThing()
    {
        // default constructor
    }

    public EnhancedThing( OriginalThing src )
    {
        // copy over the significant items
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the other class is sealed you can use encapsulation in your new class, and then modify/extend the API. You can then define a implicit cast from one object to the other and use these types interchangeably **without casting**.

Whether this is suitable in your case comes down to what you intend to do, and what you are trying to achieve but it's a valuable technique. It's more useful for hiding some/all members of the original and redefining an API.

```
// no need to cast
EnhancedThing thing = new OriginalThing();
var result = thing.NewMethod();

// again no need to cast, treat as original when passing around
OriginalThing original = thing;

public class EnhancedThing
{
    private readonly OriginalThing originalThing;

    public static implicit operator OriginalThing(EnhancedThing enhancedThing)
    {
        return enhancedThing.originalThing;
    }

    public static implicit operator EnhancedThing(OriginalThing originalThing)
    {
        return new EnhancedThing(originalThing);
    }

    private EnhancedThing(OriginalThing originalThing)
    {
        this.originalThing = originalThing;
    }

    public string OriginalMethod()
    {
        return originalThing.OriginalMethod();
    }

    public string NewMethod()
    {
        var value = originalThing.OriginalMethod();
        // extra processing ...
        return value;
    }
}
```

This technique is used extensively in Sitecore to provide different data type Models from a common base implementation. One caveat if you intend to add a new data field, it will be lost on upcast.